# C# How to Moq protected class in an abstract class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I try to mock the protected class, but throw exception System.ArgumentException: 'Member Manager.handler does not exist.'. How do I mock the protected class? Below is my code.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTest4()
    {
        Mock<Manager> mock = new Mock<Manager>();

        var result = (FileHandler)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("AB.Tests.FileHandler", true);
        mock.Protected().Setup<FileHandler>("handler").Returns(result);
    }

    public abstract class Manager
    {
        protected FileHandler handler = null;
    }

    public abstract class FileHandler
    {
        protected string firstName = null;
        protected string lastName = null;
    }
```

Comment: moq works with *virtual* properties and methods. members that can be overridden. It wont be able to mock that protected **field**

Comment: You also cant create an instance of an abstract class like you are trying to do in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and do it using the [moq's protected](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#user-content-miscellaneous) extension and again using direct reflection to invoke your desired method.

A snippet would be:

```
var mockMyClass = new Mock<MyClass>();
mockMyClass.Protected().Setup<Handler>("handler").Returns(result);

// Act!
var result = (bool)mockMyClass.Object.GetType().InvokeMember("Manager",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null,
    mockMyClass.Object,
    null);

// Assert
Assert.IsTrue(result);
mockMyClass.Protected().Verify<Handler>("handler", Times.Once());
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you mean. My existing code will hit error at this line "mockMyClass.Protected().Setup<Handler>("handler").Returns(result);". Can you explain more details? Thanks

Comment: This is a basic snippet, what you need to do here, to create a protected extension, then use direct reflection to invoke your desired test. Look at the link I attached, one you understand it things will be clearer for you.